# Sign up Attaching attachments in Allure reports using onFailureCallbacks interface

Tags: allure

Current implementation for attaching screenshots for failed scenarios is as given below. I am using cucumber life cycle hooks to attach the screenshots.

Is there a different method to easily attach screenshots ?

was just trying to use the method given in this [link](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-cucumber-jvm-example)

### AttachScreenShots

```
public class AttachScreenShots {

    @Attachment(value = "Screenshots",type = "image/png")
    public byte[] screenshots(String name, WebDriver driver) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }

}
```

### BaseClass (Just for saving the driver instance)

```
public class BaseClass  {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public static void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        BaseClass.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

CheckAccountPresence

```
public class CheckAccountPresence  extends AttachScreenShots{
    WebDriver driver;
    @Given("^I have an account called \"([^\"]*)\" with TownSEND application$")
    public void iHaveAnAccountCalledWithTownSENDApplication(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println("An acount is already present with the name " + arg1);
    }
    @When("^I try to login in to the application as \"([^\"]*)\" and password as \"([a-zA-Z]+)\"$")
    public void iTryToLoginInToTheApplicationAs(String UserName, String Psswd) throws Throwable {
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        WaitUtility.waitForElementToAppear(driver, loginPage.LnkUserSubmit, 5);
        WebElement UserElement = loginPage.InputUserName;
        WebElement PsswdElement = loginPage.InputUserPswwd;
        UserElement.clear();
        PsswdElement.clear();
        UserElement.sendKeys(UserName);
        PsswdElement.sendKeys(Psswd);
        System.out.println(Psswd);
        loginPage.LnkUserSubmit.click();

    }
    @Given("^I am on TownSend login page for account presence test$")
    public void i_am_on_TownSend_login_page() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        BaseClass.setDriver(driver);
        driver.get("http://cafetownsend-angular-rails.herokuapp.com/login");
    }
    @Then("^i should be  allowed to login to the application$")
    public void i_should_be_able_allowed_to_login_to_the_application() throws Throwable {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        WaitUtility.waitForElementToAppear(driver, homePage.LnkUserLogout, 5);
        String CAFE_TOWN_TITLE = "CafeTownsend-AngularJS-Rails";
        driver.getTitle().trim().equals(CAFE_TOWN_TITLE);
    }
    @Then("^the title should be \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void the_title_should_be(String expectedPageTitle) throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedPageTitle, driver.getTitle().trim());
//        Thread.sleep(10000);
//        driver.close();
    }
    @Given("^I dont have an account called \"([^\"]*)\" with TownSEND application$")
    public void i_dont_have_an_account_called_with_TownSEND_application(String UserName) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Checked database and there is no user called " + UserName + " registered with TownSend");
    }
    @Then("^i should be getting an error called \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_should_be_getting_an_error_called(String ExpectedErrorInvalidUser) throws Throwable {
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);

        WaitUtility.waitForElementToAppear(driver, loginPage.LblErrorInvalidUser, 5);
        Assert.assertEquals(ExpectedErrorInvalidUser,loginPage.LblErrorInvalidUser.getText().trim());

        Thread.sleep(5000);
//        driver.close();
    }

    @After
    public  void tearDownDriver(Scenario scenario){
        if(scenario.isFailed()){
                screenshots("Failed Step : "+scenario.getName(),BaseClass.getDriver());
        }

        if (driver!=null) {
            driver.close();
        }
    }



}
```

### login.feature

```
Feature: Login feature for a user TOWNSEND app should have login page through which he can login to the application for creating his own/others contact in the application.

  Background: User navigates to TownSend app
    Given I am on TownSend login page for account presence test

    Scenario: testing login functionality and make sure title is "CafeTownsend-AngularJS-Rails"
      Given I have an account called "Luke" with TownSEND application
      When I try to login in to the application as "Luke" and password as "Skywalker"
      Then i should be  allowed to login to the application
      And the title should be "CafeTownsend-AngularJS-Rails"


      Scenario: testing login functionality with negative scenario
        When I try to login in to the application as "Tom" and password as "Skywalker"
        Then i should be getting an error called "Invalid username or passwords"
```

Comment: Could you please add more details to the question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. refactored with all the code.

Comment: But what is your problem/question? How to attach screenshot on failure using CucumberJVM?

Comment: Yes exactly..how should I do it with the help of OnFailureSchedulerCallback  ?